# Maven + Clover + Jenkins - How to get Coverage report and non-instrumented artifact in one command

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, clover

I am trying to run maven clover plugin to generate report as well as generate NON-instrumented artifact.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clover2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <generatePdf>true</generatePdf>
                <generateHtml>true</generateHtml>
                <licenseLocation>clover.license</licenseLocation>
                <!-- the contextFilters element has to be specified within the reporting section and will not work if you specify it in the build section. -->
                <!-- contextFilters>try,static,catch</contextFilters --> 
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

mvn clean clover2:instrument clover2:clover install

If I run above according to clover doc instument goal will run in separate lifecycle and will not affect default buildcycle. So It does but problem is I want to skip test during default build lifecycle. 
I tried following but it skipped test for both lifecycle.

mvn clean clover2:instrument clover2:clover install -DskipTests

If above works then I can simple set it up on jenkins withou creating mulitple jobs for multiple maven commands.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably not the best idea to do everything in single cryptic maven command (in the same way it is not the best idea to put all your code in a procedure). Why not splitting the command into several steps or even jobs, which will trigger one another? Moreover from CI point of view different kind of jobs ask different priority to fail fast. I do understand that it is not exactly an answer.

Comment: IMO maven should provide a way to supply different parameter to different lifecycles. e.g. mvn clean site where I can pass different parameters for clean and site lifecycle. Or within plugin configuration I should be able to configure in which lifecycle this plugin should bind. </br> Another option is to jenkins to support multiple maven command rathar then expecting user to create multiple maven profiles.

Comment: Correction agree at some extent about separation of concern. but IMO jenkins should at least support multiple maven commands. Creating a jenkins job just for producing artifact seems overkill. Think of how many CI jobs you end up for one project specially when you are developing micro services. I might be wrong.

Comment: Sure, multiple maven commands are supported if you have free style type of job. For maven type jobs there is 'M2 Extra Steps Plugin' plugin. It allows you execute maven goals before and after main build, but I've never used it in real life.